# trouble using a simple jQuery slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

okay so I am trying to reproduce a super simple jQuery slideshow at
http://www.oliverjung.de/newsletter/slideshow.html
from Jon Raash at
http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow

however it just messes up the entire layout, I made sure I followed right, any suggestion what went wrong ?

Comment: What went wrong with what? Any code you are willing to share with us? Maybe a jsfiddle illustrating the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, you're using a REALLY old jQuery build, 1.2.6. The current one is 1.7.1 and can be found on googleapis here: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Edit: It works if you wrap the setInterval call in an anonymous function, so instead of this:

```
setInterval("slideSwitch()", 5000);
```

do this:

```
setInterval(function() { slideSwitch(); }, 5000);
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/zSSq2/